# Update value PHP

Tags: php

im trying to create an update form. below is my html for year manufactured and vehicle status.

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label" >Year Manufactured:</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="yearManufactured" value="<?php if(isset($row['yearManufactured_vehicle'])) { echo $row['yearManufactured_vehicle']; } ?>">
  <option>Select</option>
   <?php
    foreach(range(1950, (int)date("Y")) as $year) {
      echo "\t<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>\n\r";
  }

  ?>
  </select>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Vehicle Status</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="yearManufactured" value="<?php if(isset($row['yearManufactured_vehicle'])) { echo $row['yearManufactured_vehicle']; } ?>">
<option>Select</option>
  <?php
    foreach(range(1950, (int)date("Y")) as $year) {
      echo "\t<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>\n\r";
      if($row['yearManufactured']==$year){
        echo "selected";
      }
  }

  ?>
</select>
  </div>
```

in the vehicle status, i used selected to makesure that the values of inserted data is displayed in the update form. is it also the same for the year manufactured? i tried to put selected inside the option field but it gave me error. how can i use selected inside foreach for the year manufactured?

Comment: Please include error

Comment: And you can just echo `selected` instead of closing the `php`, then typing it

Comment: @Swellar i edited the code and put the selected. still no change. how can i fixed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" >Year Manufactured:</label>
<select class="form-control" name="yearManufactured" value="<?php if(isset($row['yearManufactured_vehicle'])) { echo $row['yearManufactured_vehicle']; } ?>">
<option></option>
<?php for ($x = 1950; $x <= date("Y"); $x++) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $x; ?>"<?php if ($x==$row['yearManufactured_vehicle']){ ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $x; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
```